# wifi direct live camera video streaming

Tags: android, wifi, device, p2p, peer

I need to do a wifidirect p2p connection among 2 devices.. devices 1 ( the client ) should always send to device 2 (the server ) images taken from camera of device1 something like  a streaming of what device 1 camera sees.. I've found the demo that connects the 2 devices and send image from client gallery to server https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/ but now I need to modify it to streaming the live camera feed from device 1 to device 2.. and I've found this [android wifi direct live camera video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569897/android-wifi-direct-live-camera-video-stream?fbclid=IwAR0_mEAlzXL_i0QtKW6pMQYkaeASbKWqkesyK4hizSkMQdOHndb_7w5pbck) can anywone say what should I change in the first app to do that ? where do I have to put this code?

Comment: first implement this code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/ and try to understand the code and then move on to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569897/android-wifi-direct-live-camera-video-stream?fbclid=IwAR0_mEAlzXL_i0QtKW6pMQYkaeASbKWqkesyK4hizSkMQdOHndb_7w5pbck

Comment: because it took more than 10 days to understand this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/ project